# NodeJs Microsoft Azure Storage SDK Download File to Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I just started working with the Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for NodeJS (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) and already successfully uploaded my first pdf files to the cloud storage.

However, now I started looking at the documentation, in order to download my files as a node_buffer (so I dont have to use fs.createWriteStream), however the documentation is not giving any examples of how this works. The only thing they are writing is **"There are also several ways to download files. For example, getFileToStream downloads the file to a stream:"**, but then they only show one example, which is using the fs.createWriteStream, which I dont want to use.

I was also not able to find anything on Google that really helped me, so I was wondering if anybody has experience with doing this and could share a code sample with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getFileToStream` function need a writable stream as param. If you want all the data wrote to a `Buffer` instead of a file, you just need to create a custom writable stream.

```
const { Writable } = require('stream');

let bufferArray = [];
const myWriteStream = new Writable({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        bufferArray.push(...chunk)
        callback();
    }
});

myWriteStream.on('finish', function () {
    // all the data is stored inside this dataBuffer
    let dataBuffer = Buffer.from(bufferArray);
 })
```

then pass `myWriteStream` to `getFileToStream` function

```
fileService.getFileToStream('taskshare', 'taskdirectory', 'taskfile', myWriteStream, function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    // file retrieved
  }
});
```